# fetch the latest added data using linq and pfa of the table structure

Tags: linq

[Id and date fetched through query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtlH6.png)    [Table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZNcO.png)

I want to fetch the latest added data in the table using linq for cities repository.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please tell us what have you tried, where and which problems have you faced? Also what does **latest added data** mean? Is it the latest single row, latest data by country or something else?

Comment: var q = from n in db.Cities
        group n by n.Id into g
        select new {Id = g.Key, Date = g.Max(t=>t.CreateTime)};

Comment: I tried this for getting latest record that is a row added to the table

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: I am fetching all the records from city table though I need just one record with id and city name that has been inserted recently Alao find SNAPSHOT named 

Id and date fetched through query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select **only the latest row** you don't need grouping:

```
var latest = db.Cities
    .OrderByDescending(c => c.CreateTime)
    .First();
```

However, if you want the latest row for each country you'll need the grouping:

```
var latestPerCountry = db.Cities
    .GroupBy(c => c.CountryId)
    .Select(@group => @group.OrderByDescending(c => c.CreateTime).First());
```